# Redirecting links to files with a slash on a local Apache server?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I've copied a web site to my local XAMPP server but it is displaying all links with a slash.
eg "/style.css" or "/images/logo.png" when I in fact just need "style.css" or "images/logo.png".

I don't know much about modifying the Apache settings but I'm guessing this is how I can fix this?

Comment: What do you mean it is "displaying all links"?  Do you mean to say when you hover over the link you see a leading slash? Apache won't modify the output stream to change link relativity.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken in the way I'm going about finding a solution then...
All links to any file (image, other page, stylesheet etc) are preceded by a slash which I need removing.